# Django directory structure not getting created with eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I am new to Django and of course to it on Eclipse. I have installed eclipse and PyDev - able to create Python projects and run well.

However, as I am trying to create a new Django project using "New PyDev Django Project", there is no standard directory structure that is getting created with the likes of manage.py and settings.py.

Only the root directory with the project name I specify is getting created.

I know I am missing something, can someone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Very stupid answer, but did you install django properly?

When you open a python (PyDev) console in eclipse, can you do a

```
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
```

without any errors?

Comment: yes.. it is properly installed. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work yet?

Comment: I just wanted to create a project for demonstration and run into the same problem... strange... I'll take a look on it because last time it worked out without problems...
When I manualle cd into my directory and enter `python c:\django-trunk\django\bin\django-admin.py startproject testproj`, everything works fine. So this could be a work around...

Comment: djangoadmin.py startproject testproj will work for me too, from command line. However, the directory structure is not getting created from Eclipse-PyDev